# Min width and width fit content not working on text area or input

Tags: html, css

I need to have a minimum width of text area or input, small one and if the data comes larger to resize horizontaly and push the hours label.

I tried using min width and width of fit content but not working

```html
<label class="dark-regular-text">Estimated completion:</label>
<label class="regular-text u-padding-left-8"><textarea type="text" class="input--estimation " style=" min-width: 40px;
     width: fit-content; border-bottom:1px solid black"> 2123  </textarea>Hours</label>
```

I need for ex. Estimated completion: 1 Hours if The data comes bigger like this
               Estimated completion: 432 Hours

Comment: technically input and textarea don't have content so I don't think `fit-content` will have any effect

Comment: [`<textarea>` is a replaced element — it has **intrinsic dimensions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

Comment: to expand/shrink textarea according to content, you could use javaScript or if you don't need textarea you can use `div` with `contenteditable`

Comment: I have the case to be able to edit and I cannot use div

Comment: @lilo Is my answer working for you?

Comment: I need pure css html and I dont need it do resize while typing but after refresh when the data comes from db, to resize depending of the length of numbers

Comment: @lilo Pure CSS is achievable with `contenteditable="true"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use some javascript to achieve that. See working snippet:

```css
.inp {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    min-width:2px;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Estimated completion:</span>

<span> <input class="inp" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = (this.value.length + 1) + 'ch';"></span>
   

<span> Hours.</span>
```

Alternatively you can use just a span with `contenteditable="true"`